# Remove "+" from output in SAS Content Catecorization

Tags: regex, sas

I got a little problem in SAS Content Categorization. I'm working with getting out two values. Value 1 and value 2.
I use predicate_rule, so when I click on the matched string in the program I get

```
ARGUMENT 0 [val1]: 4
ARGUMENT 1 [val2]: 4
ARGUMENT 2 [valName]: Score
```

In this example 4 is just an example of a value, but my problem is that when it stand 4+4 (no space between 4, + and 4) I can't get the latest value WITHOUT the plus symbol, so I get this out

```
ARGUMENT 0 [val1]: 4
ARGUMENT 1 [val2]: +4
ARGUMENT 2 [valName]: Score
```

I only manage to get the value printet correctly if there is space between the numbers and plus symbol.

I have now crateded two regex and two predicate_rules.

This one is for the first value (val1), called: Regex1

```
REGEX:[1-5]
```

This is for the seconed value (val2), called: Regex2

```
REGEX:\+[1-5]
```

I know that I get the plus symbol printed out because of Regex2, but I can't manage to get the latest value without typing it this way.

In the main concept I have created two predicate_rules. One that should manage the score which have space between the numbers and the plus symbol, and one that should manage when there is no space between.

```
#With space
PREDICATE_RULE:(valName,val1,val2):(ORDDIST_4, "_valName{valName}", "_val1{Regex1}", "+", "_val2{Regex1}")

#Without space 
PREDICATE_RULE:(valName,val1,val2):(ORDDIST_3, "_valName{valName}", "_val1{Regex1}", "_val2{Regex2}")
```

valName only contains terms that should be in distance of the arguments so it matches correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use SAS Base function in this tool? If so, I'd look at the scan() function.

Comment: No, unfortunately I can't. The name of the tool is: SAS Enterprise Content Categorization. I'm not entirely sure what language that is used in the tool

Comment: Can you use parentheses as capturing groups?  I have no experience using ECC, but in a normal regex if I said to match `+([1-5])` it would match +4 but only capture 4.

Comment: No, I can't that either. I get a syntax error: "syntax error: invalid REGEX syntax : parenthesis must be escaped or need to use (?: for grouping at  \+([1-5]) at line:3". If I then use (?: it don't capture just the number, but everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can look at altering your 2nd regex in the predicate_rule. Since you mentioned that text pattern like 4+4 is an issue. You could probably look into Positive lookbehind to solve the issue. Positive lookbehind will help you to select your group before your main expression without including it in the result.

Pattern like below could easily solve by Positive lookbehind:

```
4+4
4 + 4
4 +4
4 4
```

Try the following regex for the 2nd predicate_rule :

```
(?<=[\+ ])[\d]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I should actually mentioned this in the opening post, but SAS Content Categorization dosn't support lookbehind.